# Problems with ChartJS "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I'm confused with this problem.

I tried it on http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZOKpxQ and it works but not on my VisualResults.jsx

I'm wondering if it may be something I'm missing?

Thanks very much! :)

```
var React = require('react');
var BarChart = require('react-chartjs').Bar;
var Chart = require('chart.js');
var VisualResults = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    var piechart = document.getElementById("myChart");
    var myPieChart = new Chart(piechart,
      {
        type: 'pie',
        data:  {
        labels: [
            "Red",
            "Blue",
            "Yellow"
        ],
        datasets: [
            {
                data: [300, 50, 100],
                backgroundColor: [
                    "#FF6384",
                    "#36A2EB",
                    "#FFCE56"
                ],
                hoverBackgroundColor: [
                    "#FF6384",
                    "#36A2EB",
                    "#FFCE56"
                ]
            }]
        },
       options: {
            responsive: true
        }
      });
    return(
          <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    )
  }
});
module.exports = VisualResults;
```

Comment: i think u r missing `.getContext("2d")` here.

Comment: @MayankShukla that's not it, even if i get rid of .getContext("2d") on codepen the code still run and works.

Comment: Where are you using `length` in here? The error is saying you're trying to access the `length` property on something that is `null`.Your codepen works. Make sure you're including everything.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the answer is that the  tag appears after the Chart code that is trying to get a context to it. Here's an example of an HTML page where the  tag is correctly placed. After checking the chartjs documentation it doesn't appear to state explicitly about the importance of the order of the script and the tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head> 
    <title>Chart Test App</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<b>Chart Example</b>

<!--  It's critically important that the <canvas> tag appears before the script where the chart context is created
      If the <canvas> tag appears after the chart context you will receive a 
      "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null" error -->

<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>

<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```